Saves’ private notes has some escaped HTML on sites where I'm a moderator
There’s a bug with the private notes for Saves, but I can only manage to reproduce it on the site on which I'm a moderator. This does not happen on sites where I'm not a moderator.


On Music.SE, go to some question page,

Click on the Saves icon,

Then, in the pop-up, click on Manage.
The Save to window shows, but the private note is pre-filled with some HTML code:

               </div>

           <div class="d-flex gs8 gsx s-modal--footer mt16">
               <button class="s-btn s-btn__filled js-save-manage-submit" type="submit">Done</button>
               <button class="flex--item s-btn js-modal-close" type="button">Cancel</button>
           </div>
           <button class="s-modal--close s-btn s-btn__muted js-modal-close js-last-tabbable" type="button" aria-label="Close">
               <svg aria-hidden="true" class="m0 svg-icon iconClearSm" width="14" height="14"  viewBox="0 0 14 14"><path  d="M12 3.41 10.59 2 7 5.59 3.41 2 2 3.41 5.59 7 2 10.59 3.41 12 7 8.41 10.59 12 12 10.59 8.41 7 12 3.41Z"/></svg>
           </button>
       </form>
   </div>
</aside>


The Done and Cancel buttons are also missing:




It looks like something has caused part of the HTML code for that page to escape.
I don’t know why it’s only effecting my Music.SE account, but I do have literally hundreds of Saves there.  Also, I am a moderator on that site, which potentially has something to do with it.

This was reported over on MSE earlier today, the reason it seems to affect only one site is that it only affects moderators. The staff answer says its been fixed internally, and should ship out soon!

@Makyen is it fixed? The other one on MSO isn't marked as completed yet, and fixing "internally" (whatever it means) does not mean it will be pushed to production, it can be aborted.

@ShadowWizard No, it is not yet fixed.

@ShadowWizard It seems to be fixed now.
